# Почему не отображается шрифт Helvetica?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, шрифты

При загрузке страницы, большая часть текста не отображается, но занимает место. Пробовал множество способ решения проблемы, ничего не помогает.
Вот код шрифта:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Helvetica Light';
src: url('/fonts/helvetica/helvetica_light.eot');
src: url('/fonts/helvetica/helvetica_light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/helvetica/HelveticaLightCyllic.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/helvetica/helvetica_light.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/helvetica/helvetica_light.svg#HelveticaLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-display: swap;
font-style: normal;}
```

Comment: У вас шрифт то грузится в браузере? Открывайте инструменты разработчика, вкладку сеть и делайте загрузку страницы.

Comment: Шрифт загружается.

Comment: Как шрифт применяете на странице? Пример кода.